# Export DML with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, dml

I need to export particular objects and their references to DML , another application would then take file with DML and import it. DB schemas are the same ofcourse.

Is there some tool to do this or i must use mysql dump with options?

I appreciate all the advices

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Liquibase for DB Change migration from one DB to another DB with same schema.

ITs a really very great tool for maintaint DB changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this tool and see if it satisfy your needs :) http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/

Comment: This is for SQL server, not MySQL as the OP mentioned in their post.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't directly answer you question, but given the fact that I don't think there is a reliable solution using your desired approach I'll post here.

Have you tried using MySql replication instead to allow the databases to synchronize themselves without having to worry about it at the application layer.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Answer (score 1):

See [SchemaExport.execute](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html#execute%28boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) method. Set the output file and pass 'false' for all values except for 'justCreate' and 'justDrop'(assuming you are interested in drop script as well). However this will generate schema for all entities.